# How to output points using TerraScan based on selected shape and text of block boundary

Tags: lidar, terrascan

For those of you who are familiar with TerraScan, does anyone know how to save/output LAS files based on selected shape and text of block boundaries (tile index)?

The [TerraScan User Guide](https://www.terrasolid.com/download/tscan.pdf) is pretty useless.  I've tried selecting shapes and text, and running a macro with FnScanOutput(), using variable #block.las, Inside fence only.  I've tried creating a project with only the desired files, and running the macro without "inside fence only" selected on the whole project.  I can't seem to get anything to work.

[image: TS Output Points Macro step]

Answer (score 1):

The shape you select needs to be a fence.

1. Choose "Create Fence".
2. Select "By Element" from the dialogue pop-up.
3. Select the shape you want to use. Obviously this must be a closed shape.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding boundaries to a project with 'selected strings' and then importing points to those blocks

Comment: Please expand on why this solution will answer the question. Also explain how to implement. We prefer longer answers as per the Help FAQ.